# How to bind the data using ng-model in table row (inline editing)

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I have 3 values in an object **empID,empName,empEmail** like this
my problem is in the function gettemplete function(),

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp' , []);

app.controller('myCtrl' , function($scope){
    $scope.count=0;
$scope.employees = [{empID:$scope.count+1,empName:'lin',empEmail:'b@1.in'},{empID:$scope.count+1,empName:'test',empEmail:'aaa@3.com'}];
    $scope.employeeData = {};
    $scope.selected = {};

    $scope.addEmployee = function(){

        $scope.employees.push({
            empName : $scope.empName,
            empEmail : $scope.empEmail
        });
        console.log($scope.employees);
    };

    $scope.deleteEmployee = function(employee){
        var index = $scope.employees.indexOf(employee);
        $scope.employees.splice(index,1);
        console.log($scope.employees);
    };

    $scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
        if (employee.empID === $scope.selected.empID){
            console.log(employee.empID);
            console.log($scope.selected.empID);
            console.log("edit");
            return 'edit';
        }

        else {
            console.log("display");
            console.log(employee.empID);
            console.log($scope.selected.empID);
            return 'display';
        }
    };

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.selected = {};
        console.log($scope.selected);

    };

    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.addEmployee();
    };

    $scope.editEmployee = function (employee) {
        $scope.selected = angular.copy(employee);
        console.log($scope.selected);
        console.log(employee);
        console.log($scope.selected);
    };

    $scope.updateEmployee = function(employee) {
        $scope.employees.push({
            empName : $scope.empName,
            empEmail : $scope.empEmail
        });
        console.log($scope.employees);
        $scope.getTemplate();
        $scope.reset();
    };
});
```

Here goes my html code

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>
            <h3>List Employees</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <th>empID</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Employee Email</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-include="getTemplate(employee)">
                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
                            <td>{{employee.empID}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.empName}}</td>
                            <td>{{employee.empEmail}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editEmployee(employee)">Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
                            <td>{{employee.empID+ 1}}</td>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.empName class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.empEmail class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateEmployee(employee)">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
                            </td>
                        </script>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <table>
            <button ng-click="add()"> Add row </button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I am able to display my empName and empEmail but I dont know how to display **empID**. I have a button called *addrow* to create a row in the table, so when I click that button I need the empID as counted a 3,4,5,...etc like that.

Comment: you forgot to add `<input type="number" />`

Comment: i tryed to add type="number" but i get in a text field but i dont need a textfield i just need to display the number not inside the textfield

Comment: Can you provide your code which is run when addrow is clicked?

Comment: you could to put the templates script out of the loop.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Sry i am not getting you

Comment: please create a plunker and provide us

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/6nHuvFHxFMVWRLho0Nxr

Comment: I said move all <script type="text/ng-template"> immediatly before the </body> tag, removing from ng-repeat scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your addEmployee function as below.

```
$scope.addEmployee = function(){

    $scope.employees.push({
        empId : $scope.count++,
        empName : $scope.empName,
        empEmail : $scope.empEmail
    });
    console.log($scope.employees);
};
```

If you are creating few sample employees, make sure you add them via addEmployee function. That way count increases automatically. However, if you want to statically create some employees, assign count correctly. cheers.

Comment: thanks for your answer it worked but when ever i click save button i am getting a new row

Comment: It is so because, in your updateEmployee function, you are pushing a new employee instead of updating an existing employee. It is wrong.  You need to update the existing employee but not insert a new employee.

Answer (score 0):

your empId is not a number, its a string

**change this**

```
empID:'1'
```

**To this**

```
empID:1
```

So your array

```
$scope.employees = [{empID:1,empName:'lin',empEmail:'b@1.in'},{empID:2,empName:'test',empEmail:'aaa@3.com'}];

<input type="number"  ng-model="employee.empID" class="form-control input-sm"/>
```

to increment employeeId you can do like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveEmployee(employee); empId = empId+1" ng-init="empId=1">Save</button>

Current count = {{empId}}
```